# How does SQLAlchemy load related objects from the local identity map for a simple many-to-one relationship?

Tags: sql, database, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, lazy-loading

According to the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#lazy-loading):

> The one case where SQL is not emitted is for a simple many-to-one
>   relationship, when the related object can be identified by its primary
>   key alone and that object is already present in the current `Session`.
>   For this reason, while lazy loading can be expensive for related
>   collections, in the case that one is loading lots of objects with
>   simple many-to-ones against a relatively small set of possible target
>   objects, lazy loading may be able to refer to these objects locally
>   without emitting as many SELECT statements as there are parent
>   objects.

Assume that:

1. A `Parent` can have many `Child`, while a `Child` has only one `Parent`.
2. `Parent` has a relationship `children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent', lazy='select')`
3. `parent_0` is an instance of `Parent` and `child_0`, `child_1` are instances of `Child`, whose `parent` is `parent_0`.

If I've understood it correctly, this means the first time I access `parent.children`, SQLAlchemy would check the local identity map for related objects (i.e. `Child` instances referencing `parent_0`), and would query the database if nothing is found.

My question is, how does it know which `Child` instances are related to `parent_0` without querying the database? Even if all `Child` instances have been loaded to the local identity map, this only means *"all `Child` instances can be accessed through their primary keys without having to query the database"*, or alternatively *"given a specific primary key, it can return a `Child` instance without having to query the database"*. The problem is, without querying the database,how does SQLAlchemy know what the primary keys of the related objects of `parent_0` are?

If it don't know, then I can't understand how loaded `Child` instances can help to bypass the database query.

Comment: No, it means that after you access `parent_0.children`, accessing `child_0.parent` and `child_1.parent` are identity map lookups, because (presumably) `child_0` and `child_1` have a `parent_id` column that contains the primary key of the parent.

Comment: @univerio The docs says _…when the related object can be identified by its primary key alone…_ So what's "the related object"? I thought it's always `Child` instances, but it seems that it can also be `Parent` instances, depending on the context?

Comment: No, it's always `Parent` instances, because it has to be a *many-to-one* relationship. On a many-to-one relationship, the "related object" is the "one" side of the relationship, i.e. the side that is related to multiple of the other side, in this case `Parent`.

Comment: @univerio Ah that's the point! And I suppose on a many-to-many/one-to-one relationship, either side can be the related object, right?

Comment: @univerio But wait... So SQL statements will always be emitted when accessing `parent.children`, and `lazy='select'` can only speedup the access of `child_0.parent` and `child_1.parent`?

Comment: The related object is with respect to the "owner" of the relationship, i.e. for the `Child` model and the `parent` relationship therein, the related model of the relationship is `Parent`. It does not have anything to do whether a relationship is many-to-one/many-to-many. The note refers to many-to-one relationships, so in your specific case only `Child` has a many-to-one relationship (i.e. `parent`), so that's the only case the note applies to. (`Parent` has a **one-to-many** relationship to `Child`, so it doesn't apply.)

Comment: SQL will *always* be emitted when you attempt to access `parent.children` and it's not already loaded. The act of accessing an unloaded relationship will cause it to be loaded, so subsequent accesses will not emit SQL (unless it is by various mechanisms unloaded).

Comment: @univerio Your statements are really enlightening and defintely qualified as an answer. If you care to make them an answer, I would upvote and accept it!

Comment: @univerio Just in case: having `children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')` on `Parent` is functionally equivalent to having `parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')`, and having either is also equivalent to having both, and this doesn't affect what the "owner" of a relationship is, right?

Comment: That's not correct. Having `children = relationship('Child', backref='parent')` on `Parent` is equivalent to having `parent = relationship('Parent', backref='children')` on `Child`. These, in turn, are equivalent to having both `children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')` on `Parent` **and** having `parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')` on `Child`. A backref is just a reflexive relationship on the remote side. For the purposes of this discussion, the "owner" is the class containing the property, i.e. `Parent` for `children`, and `Child` for `parent`.